# System of DE using SageMath

Tags: python, python-3.x, sage

**I'm trying to solve a system of 1st order non-linear differential equation using SageMath. It is returning the desired output for a particular initial condition but i' m not able to simulate for an array of data. Here is the snippet of my code**

```
var('a x1 x2 x3 x10 x20 x30')
x10 = -8 ; x20 = 5  ; x30 = 2.6    

de_x1 = (diff(x1,a) == -4 -3*x1+2*x3 -x1*x3 +x1*x1)
de_x2 = (diff(x2,a) == 8 - 4 *x3 + x2*x1 - 2 *x2*x3 + 4*x2)
de_x3 = (diff(x1,a) == -8 +8*x3 -2*x3*x3 )
end_points = 5000
stepsize = 1.0
steps = end_points/stepsize
ics = [0,x10,x20,x30]

des = [de_x1.rhs(), de_x2.rhs(), de_x3.rhs()]
sol = desolve_system_rk4(des,[x1,x2,x3],ics,ivar=a,end_points=end_points,step=stepsize)
sol_x1=[]; sol_x2=[]; sol_x3=[]

for i in range(steps):
    sol_x1.append(sol[i][0])
    sol_x2.append(sol[i][1])
    sol_x3.append(sol[i][2])
a = plot([],figsize=[6,4])
a.axes_labels(['x1','x2'])
show(a)
```

**In the execution of for loop i am getting an error message**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-3ed005c9d4d9> in <module>()
     14 sol_x1=[]; sol_x2=[]; sol_x3=[]
     15 
---> 16 for i in range(steps):
     17     sol_x1.append(sol[i][Integer(0)])

TypeError: 'sage.rings.real_mpfr.RealNumber' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the fact that the argument you're passing to `range` isn't a Python `int`. Convert it to an int either when you compute it:

```py
steps = int(end_points/stepsize)
```

or when you pass it to `range`:

```py
for i in range(int(steps)):
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It's working properly.